# Linq-to-SQL DataContext.GetTable Issue (Sequence Contains More Than One Element)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL with the Repository pattern for the persistence layer.  My application is encountering the following error: "sequence contains more than one element" when the code is invoking the GetTable.ToList() method on the datacontext.  I am aware of why this exception would be thrown if I am using methods such as SingleOrDefault, FirstOrDefault, etc... but, I cannot understand why this exception is being thrown when the application is merely fetching the table and converting it to a list.  Can someone please share their thoughts?

```
// Causes "Sequence contains more than one element" error
dao.All().ToList();

// Below is the implementation for the All method used in the statement above
// that resides in my Repository class that all DAOs extend
public IEnumerable<T> All()
{
    return GetTable;
}

// Implementation of GetTable property in Repoistory class where db is datacontext
public System.Data.Linq.Table<T> GetTable
{
    get { return db.GetTable<T>(); }
}
```

Comment: What does fillVesselListView do?

Comment: @Oliver fillVesselListView merely takes the result of the query (i.e. List) and fills a ListView control.  The dao.All().ToList() is the piece that is throwing the exception.  I will update the post and remove the fillVesselListView method call since it is irrelevant.